# Two images comprising the background for a div?

Tags: css, background

I need to create the following in CSS and have it work on IE7+ (and Firefox if possible):

[image]

Everything is done except the background!

The quotation is different each time, so the background needs to automatically adjust in height.

It also needs to auto adjust to the width of the container it's placed within. By this, I mean the gradient cannot stretch. The background needs to be the fade-in left gradient, then the background colour, then the fade-out right gradient.

Here's my current code - **[now on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arangas/7GEah/)**:

**HTML**

```
<div id="ehs-quotecontainer">
    <div id="ehs-bgleft">
    </div>
    <div id="ehs-bgright">
    </div>
    <div class="ehs-marks" id="ehs-marktop">                    
        “
    </div>
    <span class="ehs-quotetext">Once you believe anything, you stop thinking about it.</span>
    <div class="ehs-marks" id="ehs-markbottom">
        ”
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#ehs-quotecontainer  {
    padding-top:8px;
    padding-bottom:8px;
    background-color:#F7F8FA;
    text-align:center;
}
#ehs-bgleft {
    background:transparent url(../images/ehsbgleft.jpg) repeat-y scroll right top;
}
#ehs-bgright {
    background:transparent url(../images/ehsbgright.jpg) repeat-y scroll right top;
}
.ehs-marks {
    height:20px;
    color:#8B8C90;
    font-size:5.0em;
}
#ehs-marktop {
    float:left;
    margin-top:-18px;
}
#ehs-markbottom {
    float:right;
    margin-top:-5px;
}
.ehs-quotetext {
    padding-left:4px;
    padding-right:4px;
    color:#000;
    font-size:1.1em;
    font-style:italic;
}
```

Any ideas on how to make the background work correctly?

Comment: @Alex Can you set up a demo on jsfiddle or somewhere else?

Comment: For starters, you'd want markup more like this:
<p><span class="ldquo">“</span>No task is so important or urgent that it cannot be done safely.<span class="rdquo">”</span></p>

You should really specify which browsers you care about.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: Now set up on JSFiddle. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @reisio: CSS is fairly new to me so thanks for the tip. I've updated the question giving browsers and a JSFiddle link.

Comment: @reisio, that's very much not semantic markup. You should be wrapping the quote in either `blockquote` or `q` elements. If you *have* to add extra elements to your quotations, it should probably be done via JavaScript. Messing up the markup just to adjust the style is always a bad idea.

Comment: No, a p is fine. It's not really a "long quotation" (is.gd/naC3Hy), and it shouldn't be an inline element. If you have to add extra elements to your quotations, span is the perfect element to do it inline. Adding JavaScript to accomplish something you can do with HTML alone is usually a bad idea.  That said I don't see a problem with using blockquote for the container in the answer I gave below.  Traditionally you have to put a block element inside the blockquote anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to make the entire quote `position:relative` so that you can position things inside it, relative to the quote container.

After that what you ask is fairly easy to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/7GEah/1/

Answer (score 1):

Something like this: http://www.webdevout.net/test?012&raw

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Allerta' rel='stylesheet'>
        <style>
body {
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeMeV.png) no-repeat 8px 8px;
    margin: 71px 8px 8px;
}
.quote {
    border: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
    position: relative;
    padding: 8px 35px;
}
.quote 
p {
    margin: 0;
    font: italic 12px sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.quote .w, 
.quote .e {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 75px;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(http://img526.imageshack.us/img526/1796/gradientj.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
.quote .w { left: 0; background-position: -75px 0; }
.quote .e { right: 0; background-position: 0 0; }
.quote 
span {
    color: #898a8e;
    font: 70px/70px allerta, serif;
    position: absolute;
}
.quote 
.ldquo {
    left: -35px;
    top: -15px;
}
.quote 
.rdquo {
    right: -35px;
    bottom: -42px;
}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="width: 209px;">
            <div class="quote">
                <p><span class="ldquo">“</span>No task is so important or urgent that it cannot be done safely.<span class="rdquo">”</span></p>
                <div class="w"></div>
                <div class="e"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've gone with David's answer b/c that helped me the most but upvoted your answer as it has taught me about the importance of using `p` and an alternate way this could have been done.

Comment: They use the same approach really, this one just has better markup and works in IE7, and should have less surprises across browsers in general due to the use of a web font for the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Could you create a single image, with the gradient meeting in the middle? If so, you can use:

```
#ehs-quotecontainer {
    background: (YOUR_OUTER_EDGE_COLOR) url(../images/ehsbgMerged.jpg) repeat-y center center;
}
```

Provided you have defined edges of your box (which it seems you have), this will always center the gradiant image on your text.

I should add, that if your image is too narrow, your background color will blend with the edges of the image rather than spread out the middle, which might not be what you're looking for.

Comment: That's an interesting way to look at it. Problem is the edges are not defined, and could be wider than the gradient image. I may have to fix them to a certain width.

Answer (score 0):

i hate to say this but since you will be using a very small image would you not rather use  the background and insert your text having your background .

so here you will :

1. you keep the background with the quotation marks as it is
2. Insert your text in a  with the background that you have . And finally you can just give the text some padding . and you are ready to go .

Comment: Unfortunately the customer has requested that the gradient look like the screenshot. It's not allowed to stretch. Or else this would be much easier!